# Rails: Why doesnt all my scss files get compiled?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sass

I am a beginner in rails, and I reckon I haven't got a clear idea on to how the stylesheets should be organised. Currently, I have two files in my assets/stylesheets:

- application.css
- home.css

When I run rake assets:precompile - I realise that only application.css is compiled into my public/assets folder. What about home.css?

**More Info**

I want home.css to load only when the respond is received from my home controller. I have removed  *= require_tree . from application.css (since I am guessing that home.css would be included in all other pages - am I right?)

The reason I am trying to figure out a solution for this is because heroku throws the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (home.css isn't precompiled):
2012-04-29T10:48:20+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
2012-04-29T10:48:20+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:     = stylesheet_link_tag "application"
2012-04-29T10:48:20+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:     = javascript_include_tag "application"
2012-04-29T10:48:20+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:     = stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller]
2012-04-29T10:48:20+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:     = javascript_include_tag [:controller]
2012-04-29T10:48:20+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:     = csrf_meta_tags
2012-04-29T10:48:20+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:   %body
2012-04-29T10:48:20+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-29T10:48:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.haml:8:in `_app_views_layouts_application_haml__2082158123561350666_35885340'
2012-04-29T10:48:20+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /] miss
```

Any ideas what the problem/mistake is? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default only application.css is compile (see [the guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production)). If you want to change what is precompiled, change `config.assets.precompile` in application.rb, for example

```
config.assets.precompile += ['home.css']
```

Comment: would I have to tell it to precompile every css file? (I think I will have css files for every controller). Or is that bad practice?

Comment: I think this is not the best practice to have a separate css for each controller. Usually (in simple cases) are all compiled into one huge file, and loaded once.
You can split files as you like, but eventually it will be a big one.

Comment: Okay. I understand now. One last doubt - how do I go around having a different background, for example for all my user pages (loaded by the user controller) to the rest of the app's background?

Comment: I normally set classes on the body tag or on the container div in the layout to allow for this sort of stuff

Comment: ~Newton, maybe you got this, but just to be clear, and for others who might read this thread, the standard way is to compile application.css, but application.css.scss lists all the other files, and they get compiled into one output.

Comment: thanks everyone. I am going to work on cleaning up my css files so that they don't conflict with each other when compiled into application.css.