# Implementing SCSS file to work on my Ruby on Rails app

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know there are several other questions on StackOF for implementing and importing your SCSS file into your CSS file. I went over them and I still could not find a suitable reason why my SCSS was not loading.

This is my in my application.html.erb file

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all",
                                           "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>    
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

This is my application.css file. These are the only thing uncommented.

```
*= require_self

*= require_tree .
```

This is my custom.css.scss file

```
@import "bootstrap";
0ther......
```

...

I was told that how it works in rails is that from the application.css the uncommented code will automatically look for scss files inside my app/assets/stylesheets folder. It has not done that yet and I wish to know.

Comment: I would look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138946/proper-scss-asset-structure-in-rails?rq=1 or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371573/rails-why-doesnt-all-my-scss-files-get-compiled?rq=1

Comment: Are there any errors in the error log? Posting that would really help

Comment: @beautifulcoder there are no error. It simply does not output the css.